# How can I make a code more efficient and shorter?

Tags: javascript, firebase

I am making a code where the user can press one of five buttons, which get disabled after the click. Then it's supposed to count each press and store it in Firestore database, and the number be shown on the button. I have not quite managed the counting yet (tried Firestore increment), but that's for another question. I am relativity new to JavaScript, but I managed to display the number of votes, but the code is way too long and inefficient. This is my code for the buttons:

```
<ul>
    <li class="circleProgressVote"> <!-- Bruker enkle svar slik at knappene ikke trenger å være så store-->
        <button class="btn white black-text voteBtn" id="btn1" style="border-radius: 50%; height: 75px; width: 125px; font-size: 10px;" onclick="vote1(); disableButton();"> <span id="svar1"> Svært dårlig </span> </button>
    </li>
    <li class="circleProgressVote">
        <button class="btn white black-text voteBtn" id="btn2" style="border-radius: 50%; height: 75px; width: 125px; font-size: 10px;" onclick="vote2(); disableButton();"> Dårlig </button>
    </li>
    <li class="circleProgressVote">
        <button class="btn white black-text voteBtn" id="btn3" style="border-radius: 50%; height: 75px; width: 125px; font-size: 10px;" onclick="vote3(); disableButton();"> Usikker </button>
    </li>
    <li class="circleProgressVote">
        <button class="btn white black-text voteBtn" id="btn4" style="border-radius: 50%; height: 75px; width: 125px; font-size: 10px;" onclick="vote4(); disableButton();"> Bra </button>
    </li> 
    <li class="circleProgressVote">
        <button class="btn white black-text voteBtn" id="btn5" style="border-radius: 50%; height: 75px; width: 125px; font-size: 10px;" onclick="vote5(); disableButton();"> Svært bra </button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

To display the number of votes I gave each button their own function, but it is basically the same code. The point is that the number of votes appear on each button no matter which you press. So I made this for each of the functions where its mainly the firestore increment code and the last line (which sets the border around the chosen button) that is different:

```
function vote1() {
  console.log('ans1');

    const db = firebase.firestore();
  const increment = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1);
  const storyRef = db.collection('spørsmål').doc().collection('valg1');
  
  storyRef.update({ reads: increment });

  db.collection('spørsmål').get().then((snapshot) => {
    snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
      hentSvar1(doc);
    });
  });
  function hentSvar1(doc) {
    
   
    let div1 = document.createElement('div');
    let votes1 = document.createElement('span');
    let span1 = document.createElement('span');

    div1.setAttribute('data-id', doc.id);
    votes1.textContent = doc.data().valg1;
    span1.textContent = ' stemmer';

    div1.appendChild(votes1);
    div1.appendChild(span1);
  
    let div2 = document.createElement('div');
    let votes2 = document.createElement('span');
    let span2 = document.createElement('span');

    div2.setAttribute('data-id', doc.id);
    votes2.textContent = doc.data().valg2;
    span2.textContent = ' stemmer';

    div2.appendChild(votes2);
    div2.appendChild(span2);
   
    let div3 = document.createElement('div');
    let votes3 = document.createElement('span');
    let span3 = document.createElement('span');

    div3.setAttribute('data-id', doc.id);
    votes3.textContent = doc.data().valg3;
    span3.textContent = ' stemmer';

    div3.appendChild(votes3);
    div3.appendChild(span3);
   
    let div4 = document.createElement('div');
    let votes4 = document.createElement('span');
    let span4 = document.createElement('span');

    div4.setAttribute('data-id', doc.id);
    votes4.textContent = doc.data().valg4;
    span4.textContent = ' stemmer';

    div4.appendChild(votes4);
    div4.appendChild(span4);
    
    let div5 = document.createElement('div');
    let votes5 = document.createElement('span');
    let span5 = document.createElement('span');

    div5.setAttribute('data-id', doc.id);
    votes5.textContent = doc.data().valg5;
    span5.textContent = 'stemmer';

    div5.appendChild(votes5);
    div5.appendChild(span5);


    
    svar1.appendChild(div1);
    svar2.appendChild(div2);
    svar3.appendChild(div3);
    svar4.appendChild(div4);
    svar5.appendChild(div5);

   
    document.getElementById('btn1').style.border = '2px solid red';

  };
};
```

I know it's way too long and inefficient to have five of these almost similar functions but I can't figure out how to make it simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a function like this:

```
function appendDiv(svar, doc) {
  let div = document.createElement('div');
  let votes = document.createElement('span');
  let span = document.createElement('span');

  div.setAttribute('data-id', doc.id);
  votes.textContent = doc.data().valg1;
  span.textContent = ' stemmer';

  div.appendChild(votes);
  div.appendChild(span);
  svar.appendChild(div);
}
```

And call it like this:

```
appendDiv(svar1, doc);
appendDiv(svar2, doc);
appendDiv(svar3, doc);
appendDiv(svar4, doc);
appendDiv(svar5, doc);
```